# Conditional unset from Guzzle response

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach, guzzle

I've seen a few questions and the ones worth referencing

- [How can i delete object from json file with PHP based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50163400/5675325)
- [How do you remove an array element in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1949259/5675325)
- [How to delete object from array inside foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304570/5675325)
- [Unset not working in multiple foreach statements (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18124077/5675325)

The last two from the list are closer to what I'm intending to do.

---

I've got a variable names `$rooms` which is storing data that comes from a particular API using Guzzle

```
$rooms = Http::post(...);
```

[image]

If I do

```
$rooms = json_decode($rooms);
```

this is what I get

[image]

If I do

```
$rooms = json_decode($rooms, true);
```

this is what I get

[image]

---

Now sometimes the `group` exists in the same level as `objectId`, `visibleOn`, ... and it can assume different values

[image]

So, what I intend to do is delete from `$rooms` when

- `group` isn't set (so that specific value, for example, would have to be deleted)
- `group` doesn't have the value `bananas`.

Inspired in the last two questions from the initial list

```
foreach($rooms as $k1 => $room_list) {
    foreach($room_list as $k2 => $room){
        if(isset($room['group'])){
            if($room['group'] != "bananas"){
                unset($rooms[$k1][$k2]);
            }
        } else {
            unset($rooms[$k1][$k2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `$room['group']` needs to be changed to `$room->group` depending on if we're passing `true` in the `json_decode()` or not.

This is the ouput I get if I `dd($rooms);` after that previous block of code

[image]

Instead, I'd like to have the same result that I've shown previously in `$rooms = json_decode($rooms);`, except that instead of having the 100 records it'd give only the ones that match the two desired conditions.

Comment: So, basically you just want `if( !isset($room['group']) || $room['group'] != "bananas" )` …?

Comment: @CBroe right, that'd simplify the condition. But the problem isn't in that logic but the output

Comment: I didn’t see a `group` anywhere on any of these screenshots you have shown, so how are we supposed to tell what is going wrong now? Provide a proper [mre] of the issue, please.

Comment: @CBroe just included the image of one case with group

Comment: instead of converting into array from object have you tried to change it to collection provided by laravel then use the forget method

Comment: have you tried maybe using dd for debugging

Comment: @bhucho «instead of converting into array from object have you tried to change it to collection provided by laravel then use the forget method », I haven't tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not totally wrong, then this should do the trick for you:

```php
$rooms = json_decode($rooms);
$rooms->results = array_values(array_filter($rooms->results, function($room) {
    return property_exists($room, 'group') && $room->group != "banana";
}));
```

Here is a verbose and commented version of this one above:

```php
$rooms = json_decode($rooms);

// first lets filter our set of data
$filteredRooms = array_filter($rooms->results, function($room) {
    // add your criteria for a valid room entry
    return
        property_exists($room, 'group') // the property group exists
        && $room->group == "banana";    // and its 'banana'
});

// If you want to keep the index of the entry just remove the next line
$filteredRooms = array_values($filteredRooms);

// overwrite the original results with the filtered set
$rooms->results = $filteredRooms;
```